# How to match regex to line ending in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get python regex to match the end of a string (primarily because I want to remove a common section off the end of the string.  I have the following code which I think is how the docs describe to do it, but it's not performing as I'm expecting:

```
input_value = "Non-numeric qty or weight, from 00|XFX|201912192009"
pattern = ", from .*$"
match = re.match(pattern , input_value)
print(match)
```

The result is `None`, however I'm expecting to have matched something.  I've also tested these values with an online regex tool: https://regex101.com/ using the python flavour, and it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `search` instead of `match` which matches at start only

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.match(".*, from.*$", input_value)
```

you should use .* infront else it will try to fin exact match